# Is it possible to read Wikipedia using Python requests library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, wikipedia

To read a content from a given URL I do the following:

```
import requests
proxies = {'http':'http://user:pswd@foo-webproxy.foo.com:7777'}
url = 'http://example.com/foo/bar'
r = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies)
print r.text.encode('utf-8')
```

And it works fine! I get the content.

However, if I use another URL:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mestisko'
```

It does not work. I get an error message that starts with:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060
```

Is Wikipedia blocking automatic requests?

**ADDED**

I tried to set a user agent in the following way:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies, headers = headers)
```

Unfortunately it does not help. I still get the same error.

**ADDED 2**

Now I am confused. If I try to get content from `http://example.com/foo/bar` with setting proxy, I get it. If I do not set proxy, I get content generated by proxy. This behavior I can understand. Now, if I try to get content from Wikipedia, I get the same error message independently on whether I set or do not set proxy. So, I do not understand where this error message comes from Wikipedia or proxy (both options cannot be true).

Comment: @CharlesP, what else do i need to pass?

Comment: Works for me using urllib2

Comment: Roman -- let me play around in ipython when I get out of this meeting. I can't remember exactly.

Comment: I use `requests` with Wikipedia on a daily basis. Try it without the proxy and see if it works then.

Comment: Seems to be working fine actually. Nevermind

Comment: It's an issue with your proxy. I've removed proxy option and it worked

Comment: @felipsmartins, but why it works with other sites?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Give a try using [urllib2.ProxyHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). In adittion, make sure your proxy auth params are correct.

Comment: Also try throwing in a referrer. I forget where but once I got around a bot-blocker in part due to that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by replacing:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://user:pswd@foo-webproxy.foo.com:7777'}
```

with the following line:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://user:pswd@foo-webproxy.foo.com:7777', 'https':'http://user:pswd@foo-webproxy.foo.com:7777'}
```