# Error while crawling wikipedia data -- requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Tags: python, connection, wikipedia

I am getting an error on the line `p = wikipedia.page(line)`.

> -- requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

My INTERNET connection is working fine.
I'm Not getting what's wrong with my code.
Please help ! thanks

```
import wikipedia
import sys
import os

file_dir = sys.argv[1]
for file_name in os.listdir(file_dir):
    with open(os.path.join(file_dir, file_name)) as fd:
        while True:
            line = fd.readline()
            if len(line) == 0:
                break
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) == 0:
                continue

            p = wikipedia.page(line)
            f = open("/home/data/"+file_name,"a")
        print line
        f.write(line)
        f.write("***")
            try:
            data = p.content 
            data = data.encode("utf8")
            f.write(data)
            print " DONE"
            f.write("\n")
        except: 
            print " NOT done"
            continue
```

Comment: `Connection aborted` usually can be seen if one of the network partners (or a proxy in between) disconnects the connection. How many queries do you run against wikipedia? Maybe you hit a connection limit and the remote server blocks your subsequent connects?

Comment: @SaschaM78 I have near about 100 wiki page names, whose data I want to retrieve one by one! Error occurs after getting data from first 5-6 wiki pages

Comment: Grammar, typos, fix title, add error message to question body, formatting

Comment: Are you using a proxy to access the web? If so, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092501/is-it-possible-to-read-wikipedia-using-python-requests-library). Your best option would be to use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or something similar to see what TCP packets you receive before the error is thrown.